# writing values as headers

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I am trying to save a json response from web to csv file, the problem is that there are deeper levels and the key value pairs are to be separated and just the values need to be stored.

code:

```
import csv
import json


infile=open('oobar.json', "rb")
json_s=infile.read()
outfile=open("watsf.csv","wb")
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
count = 0

for data in(json.loads(json_s)):
    categories = data['document_tone']
    for category in categories['tone_categories']:
        for tone in category['tones']:
            if count != 5:
                header = ([tone.values()[0]])
                writer.writerow(header)
                count += 1
                writer.writerow([tone.values()[1]])
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWKAe.jpg)

[Actual output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sADFT.jpg)

Json response to parse and extract the above values

```
{
"document_tone": {
    "tone_categories": [
        {
            "category_id": "emotion_tone", 
            "tones": [
                {
                    "tone_name": "Anger", 
                    "score": 0.077068, 
                    "tone_id": "anger"
                }, 
                {
                    "tone_name": "Disgust", 
                    "score": 0.01956, 
                    "tone_id": "disgust"
                }, 
                {
                    "tone_name": "Fear", 
                    "score": 0.043762, 
                    "tone_id": "fear"
                }, 
                {
                    "tone_name": "Joy", 
                    "score": 0.764404, 
                    "tone_id": "joy"
                }, 
                {
                    "tone_name": "Sadness", 
                    "score": 0.084368, 
                    "tone_id": "sadness"
                }
            ], 
            "category_name": "Emotion Tone"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to save a json response from web to csv file, the problem is that there are deeper levels and the key value pairs are to be separated and just the values need to be stored.

Comment: You shouldn't use a nested loop here.

Comment: You can just use a `dictionary`  and have it's keys like `anger` and then just append to the key's value a list with the values.

Comment: Please do not use images to show input and output. It is better to be able to view all important information directly in the question.

Comment: @user1767754, can you show me how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the keys and values you're interested in to a intermediary dictionary (`tone_dict` in the example) and then use a `csv.DictWriter` to write the `tone_dict`.

```
data = json.loads(json_s)

fieldnames = ['Anger', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Joy', 'Sadness']
tone_dict = {}

for tone in data['document_tone']['tone_categories'][0]['tones']:
    tone_dict[tone['tone_name']] = tone['score']

with open('temp.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(tone_dict)
```

Comment: im getting this error--  for tone in data['document_tone']['tone_categories'][0]['tones']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I used the json sample in the question and it worked correctly for me (btw a curly bracket was missing at the end). Maybe your actual json data looks different.

Comment: You could add the complete traceback to the question for the moment, so that we can debug your program, and later we can clean it up.